# Destructuring the imports statement

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In the React project I found this piece of code, which is pretty much standard:

```
import React from 'react';

import {
    ImageLeft,
    ImageRight,
    ImageBottom,
    ImageBanner    
} from './content';

const LAYOUT_COMPONENT = {   
    image_left: ImageLeft,
    image_right: ImageRight,
    image_bottom: ImageBottom,
    image_banner: ImageBanner    
};
```

LAYOUT_COMPONENT object has repetitions. Is it possible somehow to create it with [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) from import statement, in order to avoid extra code?

Comment: Well, you could name them the same so you could do: `const LAYOUT_COMPONENT = {ImageLeft, ImageRight, etc etc. }` as you probably know this is the same as `const LAYOUT_COMPONENT = {ImageLeft: ImageLeft, ImageRight: ImageRight, etc etc. }` but outside of that I wouldn't change it - you need some separation

Comment: does `./content` component contains more properties other than you mentioned while importing?

Comment: content is a folder that has other components that are exported by their name. And I import all of them. There are more props (files), but I ommited them for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is [no destructuring in import statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43987935/1048572).

What you *could* do is

```
import * as contents from './content';

const LAYOUT_COMPONENT = {};
for (let p of ["Left", "Right", "Bottom", "Banner"])
    LAYOUT_COMPONENT["image_"+p.toLowerCase()] = contents["Image"+p];
}
```

but notice this will prevent a module bundler from tree shaking.