# How and why does `module.exports = {__dirname}` work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, babeljs, es6-modules

How does the code from **[here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-eps/blob/master/002-es-modules.md#4512-getting-cjs-variables-workaround)** work - and why? The object notation does not seem to be satisfied. I find it rather confusing. What does this refer to in the docs @Mozilla or @NodeJS ?

File `expose.js`:

```
module.exports = {__dirname};
```

File `use.mjs`:

```
import expose from './expose.js';
const {__dirname} = expose;
```

So shouldn't this actually work, importing only key from the object, in `use.mjs`? (which doesn't ... but above does!)

```
import {__dirname} from './expose.js';
```

**edit**: I usually do something like `import electron, {ipcMain, session} from 'electron';` - importing the whole name space, then specific parts directly as needed. As well as `import {inspect} from 'util';`. So deconstruction should be in place here

**edit 2**: [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43987935/1644202), from the thread mentioned by willascend below. The **No.** part explains what the problem with the line in my question was.

Comment: Are you just asking about the `{__dirname}` syntax? In which case that's ECMA's new shorthand syntax for object creation. Search for "shorthand" [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). `{a}` will create an object with key `"a"` and value of whatever `a` evaluates to

Comment: And `const {__dirname} = expose;` is deconstructing to local variable `__dirname` ? So why does the last import not work?

Comment: Well, `__dirname` is a special keyword, so there may be some difficulties in importing it like that. What error do you get? Try importing all of expose.js and see what the object contains

Comment: Inside a .mjs there are no magic globals prepended. So no `__dirname`. That's why this script is required. The question still remains.

Comment: @BananaAcid, please see my answer. I think it explains what's going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a simple object literal with the property name matching the value:

```
let ___test = 'this is a string... could be a path';
let object = {___test};

console.log(object);
```

Using `module.exports`, you've exported an object. When importing using the module system, you essentially have a module scoped object, `expose`. You then destructure that object's `__dirname` property when defining `{__dirname}`. I haven't tested it, but you should be able to just import `__dirname` as a named import like so (though you'd likely run into a conflict for the variable name):

```
import __dirname from './expose.js';
```

EDIT: Did some testing, when you do the above import, you get your exported object, so you would still need to destructure after importing (and of course, destructure into a new variable):

```
import __dirname from './expose.js';
const {__dirname: dirname} = __dirname;
console.log(dirname);
```

After some googling, it appears you cannot destructure an object when performing an ES6 import. The syntax appears similar to destructuring an object but it is not. What you are doing when you do the following is actually import variables that have been exported as named exports.

### *test.mjs*

```
export const __dirname = 'this is a path';
```

### *test-import.mjs*

```
import { __dirname } from './test.mjs';
console.log(__dirname);
```

Note that I didn't use `export const __dirname = __dirname;`, or even `export const dirname = __dirname;`. This is because node specific globals aren't available in `.mjs` files currently. So, in your example, `expose.js` is still a standard .js file which has access to both the `module` and `__dirname` globals. The `__dirname` value is then exported as a property of the **default** commonjs export object (i.e. `module.exports = {__dirname}`), which is then made available as the **default** export when importing in your `use.mjs` file. The `expose` variable is the module.exports object literal that was exported. Once it's been initialized as an imported variable, you can then destructure out the __dirname value.

Hope this helps.

These other sources were helpful for me in understanding this as well: [Destructuring a default export object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43814830/destructuring-a-default-export-object)
https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/194#issuecomment-168579479
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/16844#issuecomment-342245465

Comment: The links: nice finds ! Specifically the 1st let to what was my question -  Quoted from there: "No. What it does is to declare an invisible variable, initialise it with the object { foo: foo, bar: bar }, and export it under the name default."

Answer (score 0):

This is object shorthand in ES2015 ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)).

`{__dirname}` is equal to `{__dirname: __dirname}`

For example:

```js
var a = 'foo', b = 42, c = {};
var o = {a, b, c};

console.log(o);
```