# What is the purpose of "default export" in ES modules?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

ES modules have the concept of "default export" and "default import", which looks like this:

```js
export default foo;             // roughly sugar for: const tmp = foo; export { tmp as default }
import d from './myModule.js';  // roughly sugar for: import { default as d } from './myModule.js'
```

This concept is not one that I have met in any other module systems in other languages. It caused much confusion for me when I first met it, and it seems like it causes much confusion for other people too. The concept also seems to provide no additional power, compared to named exports.

**So: why does this "default export" feature exist? What problem is it solving? [The spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) doesn't seem to provide any reasoning for it.**

Comment: I'm inclined to close as a duplicate of [Why does JavaScript have default exports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57020740/why-does-javascript-have-default-exports), but you recently edited an post in there so you must remember it. How does my answer there not provide the reasoning you're looking for?

Comment: Maybe (1) encourage a script-writer to write modules that do (and export) one thing, and one thing only (2) allow scripts to specify a *main thing* that they're exporting (eg React) but also have related side things they're exporting (eg useEffect). Whether those reasons are good enough to justify it is opinion-based, though

Comment: I think any answer would be speculation unless they were involved in writing the spec.  I don't know that this is directly answerable.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I would say it's meant to *enable* them to do that, not to *encourage* them. Modules that export only one thing were widely popular before ES6 was designed, and it was considered a problem to force the naming of exports in that common use case.

Comment: @Bergi aha, I had a vague memory of seeing this question somewhere, but was unable to find it again! ‍♂️