# Unexpected behavior when using "import * as" and destructuring

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Files look like this:

```
-test
--index.js
--test1.js
--test2.js
```

test1.js:

```
export const val1 = "TEST 1";
export const val2 = "TEST 2";
export const val3 = "TEST 3";
export const val4 = "TEST 4";
```

test2.js:

```
export const val5 = "TEST 5";
export const val6 = "TEST 6";
export const val7 = "TEST 7";
export const val8 = "TEST 8";
```

index.js:

```
import * as test1 from "./test1";
import * as test2 from "./test2";

export default { ...test1, ...test2 };
```

In another file:

```
import { val6 } from "./test";
```

The variable `var6` is undefined.

However if I do this:

```
import test from "./test";
const { val6 } = test;
```

then var6 is defined and is equal to "TEST 6".

The test1 and test2 objects have the key `__esModule: true`.

I don't understand why this is the case. Why is var6 undefined in the first example?

Comment: When you `export default { ... }`, the entire object literal is the default export, they are not named exports. `import { val6 }` uses the named export of `./test`, which doesn't exist, but `import test` and `const { val6 } = test` destructures the property `val6` from the default export of `./test` which is correct in this case.

Comment: How do I combine exports from several files?

Comment: [Destructuring a default export object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43814830)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in the comments, you are creating a default-exported object literal, which is not the same as having named exports (it results in `test` referring to the combined object, but no other exports besides `default`). It seems what you are actually looking for is

```
// index.js:
export * from "./test1";
export * from "./test2";
```

With that, you can use

```
import { val6 } from "./test";
console.log(val6);
// or
import * as test from "./test";
console.log(test.val6);
```