# How to exports all class members use one line in js? version >= es6

Tags: javascript

It seems this can possible in es5 and imagine NextI18Next got some functions in it:

```js
module.exports = new NextI18Next({
  otherLanguages: ['ko'],
  defaultLanguage: 'en',
  ns: ['translations'],
  defaultNS: 'translations',
  localePath: path.resolve('../../public/locales'),
})

///////////
import { appWithTranslation, ... } from "..."
appWithTranslation()
```

So you can exports all class members simply just use `module.exports`, but
in es6 >= version

You should use like this:

```js
const i18n = new NextI18Next({
  otherLanguages: ['ko'],
  defaultLanguage: 'en',
  ns: ['translations'],
  defaultNS: 'translations',
  localePath: path.resolve('../../public/locales'),
})

export default i18n
export const appWithTranslation = i18n.appWithTranslation
export const useTranslation = i18n.useTranslation
// ...

///////// 
import { appWithTranslation, ... } from "..."
appWithTranslation()
```

It seems you can't exports all class members in es5 does.

Is there are ways to exports all class members simply like es5?

Answer (score 0):

#### Static Imports:

For static imports, you can use [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) do something like:

```
export default new NextI18Next({
  otherLanguages: ['ko'],
  defaultLanguage: 'en',
  ns: ['translations'],
  defaultNS: 'translations',
  localePath: path.resolve('../../public/locales'),
})
```

and then import like so:

```
import myModule from "...";
const { appWithTranslation, ... } = myModule;
```

I believe that for static imports, all exports need to be named or default; you can't import anything that isn't explicitly exported. In this case `appWithTranslation` isn't explicitly exported, so I think the best you can do is with two lines, importing the default object with one line, and destructuring assignment with another.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/43987935

#### Dynamic imports

In the case of dynamic imports, you *can* use destructuring assignment to import it in one line:

```
(async function () {
  const { default: { appWithTranslation } } = await import('./filename.js');
  appWithTranslation();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to spell out named exports explicitly in ES6.

In most cases, you shouldn't export class member - especially unbound methods - individually anyway if they are already part of an exported instance object.