# Unable to test when exporting with curly braces

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component that needs to be exported as follows due to some usages by other components.

I can't change this (can't remove the curly brackets):

```
export default { MyComponent }; // test fails due to braces
```

How could I test this. Cos currently when I test this simply via a snapshot test, I get the following error:

> Error: ReactShallowRenderer render(): Shallow rendering works only
> with custom components,  but the provided element type was `object`.

Now if I remove the curly braces as follows, the test passes. But can't do that because it needs to remain with the curly braces.
Is there a way around this to test this component?

```
export default MyComponent; // test passes but in reality I need to stick with the curly braces.
```

Note: I am trying to stick with using shallow instead of mount.

MyComponent

```
const MyComponent = ({ ref }) => {
  const config = {
    sample: {
      ref,
    },
  };

  return (
    <DataComponent
      config={config}
    />
  );
};

export default { MyComponent };
```

Test failing with above error when I use the curly braces during export.

```
it('should work', () => {
  expect(shallow(
    <MyComponent
      ref='testref'
    />
  )).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Comment: *Why* does it need "to remain with the curly braces"? Note that `export default { MyComponent }` (an object as the default export) is not the same as `export const MyComponent = ...` (a function as a named, non-default export) - `import { MyComponent } from "wherever"` would only work with the latter (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/43814830/3001761).

Comment: *due to some usages by other components* - you need to use it the same way as it's used elsewhere. Currently the only correct way to use it is `import myComponentObj from "wherever"; const { MyComponent } = myComponentObj`, and it looks like somebody wasn't comfortable enough with ESM when writing this.