# Vue3 / Vite: How to package components for publishing on npm

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, npm-publish, vite

I'm trying to export two  web components in a public package on npm, using Vite with TypeScript.

Vite has a [Library Mode](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode) which works well. The ESM and UMD files are both being transpiled into my `/dist` directory. My question is how to export the web components in the entry point file.

I have an entry point file called `export.js`

```js
import AwesomeHeader from './components/AwesomeHeader.vue'
import AwesomeFooter from './components/AwesomeFooter.vue'

export default { // I feel like the problem is here.
    components: {
        AwesomeHeader: AwesomeHeader,
        AwesomeFooter: AwesomeFooter,
    }
}
```

The idea is that I'll `npm publish` the project and use it like this.

```bash
npm i @sparkyspider/awesome-components #(ficticious example)
```

```js
import {AwesomeHeader, AwesomeFooter} from '@sparkyspider/awesome-components' // does not find
```

*(AwesomeHeader and AwesomeFooter are not found as exports in the node_module, even though the JavaScript files are referenced / found)*

My package.json below:

```json
{
    "name": "@sparkyspider/awesome-components",
    "version": "1.0.8",
    "files": [
        "dist"
    ],
    "main": "./dist/awesome-components.umd.js",
    "module": "./dist/awesome-components.es.js",
    "exports": {
        ".": {
            "import": "./dist/awesome-components.es.js",
            "require": "./dist/awesome-components.umd.js"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build",
        "serve": "vite preview"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "vue": "^3.0.5"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^1.2.2",
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.5",
        "typescript": "^4.1.3",
        "vite": "^2.3.3",
        "vue-tsc": "^0.0.24"
    },
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having object `{ component: ... }` as default export, instead of exporting `AwesomeHeader` and `AwesomeFooter`, which you try to import.

`export { AwesomeHeader, AwesomeFooter }` in `export.js` will work.

More on export: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

And you can't destructure the default export: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43987935/8810271

Comment: Haha, such a simple answer - but it worked!