# Why do I get a TS2614 when import-destructure the default export of flatten-js library using ES module syntax but not when const-destructure it?

Tags: typescript, flatten-js

I wish to improve the developer experience of the [flatten-js](https://github.com/alexbol99/flatten-js) library by fixing an issue I encountered with it.

When I do

```
import { point } from '@flatten-js/core';
```

I get a TS error that point doesn't exist but if I do

```
import Flatten from "@flatten-js/core";
const { point } = Flatten;
```

then point is recognized as a member of the library. I've documented the issue [here](https://github.com/alexbol99/flatten-js/issues/98). Anyone know what might be going on?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43814830/destructuring-a-default-export-object - as they export flatten object as default you can destructure it only after importing that default. That's I don't like exporting defaults.

Comment: Add `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` in your `tsconfig` under `compilerOptions`