# Export and export default a variable

Tags: es6-modules

What's the right way to do something like this? My goal is to have my list of things I'm exporting not have to be duplicated. Right now I have to make two lists of exports, one for the export, and one for the default export.

```
const exports = {
    Something,
    SomethingElse
}

export exports

export default exports
```

My goal is to be able to import like this:

```
import everything from 'my_module'
```

or

```
import {Something} from 'my_module'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`export exports` is not valid syntax, it looks similar to [something that TypeScript did support](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require) but that is deprecated in favour of modern syntax. Do not use it.

`export default exports;` and `import everything from 'my_module';` would work together, but [it's not recommended to default-export objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43814830/1048572) since it doesn't work with named imports.

Instead, use named exports:

```
export {
    Something,
    SomethingElse
}
```

(or put the `export` right on the declarations of `Something` and `SomethingElse`), then you can choose to do either

```
import {Something} from 'my_module';
```

or

```
import * as everything from 'my_module';
```